# Application built from a .kv file does not return label

Tags: kivy, python-3.10

I've just started learing kivy in VS Code, but when I run my Python code, the window is created but the label defined in .kv file doesn't show up. What am I doing wrong?

This is my Python code:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy','keyboard_mode','systemanddock')
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.lang import Builder

GUI = Builder.load_file("display.kv")

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

app = MyApp()
app.run()`
```

And this is my Kivy display.kv file:

#:kivy 2.1.0

```
Label:
    Text: "Hello world"
```

[image: Application screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In your `kv` file, replace:

```
Text: "Hello world"
```

with:

```
text: "Hello world"
```

Note the lower case `t` in `text`.